# How to run a method in loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, background

I have a project that needs to run a method in loop and in background.

Basically I have a method that: call a web service → read the data → store into a database → loop over and over.

I found [a gem called "loops"](https://github.com/kovyrin/loops) but maybe there are 2 problems:

1. I don't know if they support Rails 3 & Ruby 1.9.3 and
2. It seems like there are no support on it (last commit was a half year ago).

Comment: What have you tried? This seems quite simple, make a thread that will run the method in a loop and start the thread.

Comment: I havent tried anything. In the way you posted, I should start the thread in app init, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Develop a simple looping program like:

```
loop do
  data = read_data_from_web_service
  store_data_to_db(data)
end
```

Configure the script in `upstart`. You can use `foreman` gem for this.
Otherwise you can use just `foreman` without `upstart` according to your convenience.
Check the [link](http://michaelvanrooijen.com/articles/2011/06/08-managing-and-monitoring-your-ruby-application-with-foreman-and-upstart/)

OR you can use some tools like `monit` to monitor the script.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a loop construct.

`loop { puts "hi" }`

Comment: he wants to run it in the background, thus me mentioning threading

Answer (score 0):

You could call the method from a rake task and then start the rake task from the command line with `nohup`.

Example:

in `lib/tasks/fetch_data.rake`

```
task :fetch_and_save => :environment do
  loop do
    Model.method() # Do whatever you need to do here
  end
end
```

You can then start it with `$ nohup rake fetch_and_save`.

Comment: Looks nice. I'll try it soon and post the results. Btw, thank you!

Comment: You could also use a process monitor like [god](https://github.com/mojombo/god) to keep it running.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your goal is to have code loop endlessly in the background.

Here are the parts you need:

```
loop do <code> end
```

will loop < code> nonstop in the current thread

```
mythread = Thread.new(<args>) do |<args>| <code> end
mythread.run
```

will run < code> in another thread (the background, aka asynchronously) and will pass the < args> to it, as if it was a function.

What you want to do, is to loop < code> inside a thread. so... (assuming you want to pass

```
myloop = lambda do loop do <code> end end
mythread = Thread.new(myloop) do |loop| loop.call end
mythread.run
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem. It's easy do this kind of work through this gem.

There's even a free [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby) on this topic.

Create a rake task that calls your method to be looped. (see other answers how to do that).

And then you can create a schedule that says, `every 1.minute` like so.